# TensorFlow: How do I restore one model's trainable variables into another?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I trained an autoencoder and saved the session using the Saver. Now I want to train a separate model, that will use a bunch of the trained variables that I have to encode the input and pass it along a MLP. The thing is that I'm having trouble loading the autoencoder model into my new model, even with the Saver's export/import functions.

Is this even possible?
I keep getting
'Could not open encoder.ckpt: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number) perhaps your file is in a different format and you need to use a different restore operator?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the variables you pass to the saver have the same name in both models then this should work. The error you mentioned, though, is unrelated. Can you post a full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be a comment, but as @Alexandre Passos mentioned, saver.restore(encoder.ckpt) should work if you have defined all of the variables/operations before. If you have not, you will need to load the stored graph as

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(encoder.ckpt.meta)
saver.restore(encoder.ckpt)
```

Then if you only want to grab some of the variables from that model, you can do so by

```
graph = tf.get_default()
restored_var = graph.get_tensor_by_name(restored_var_name)
```

You also may want to check your checkpoint file to make sure you have the write path to you encoder.ckpt file.